Weakly metrizable sets in normed spaces
A similar question was asked on MSE without getting an answer.
In the proof of lemma 1.2 of Asplund operators and holomorphic maps the author (my attempt to contact him failed because the only e-mail I have found is unvalid) seems to use the following characterization:

A bounded and absolutely convex subset $A$ of a normed space $F$ is metrizable in the weak topology if and only if there is a countable subset $M$ of the unit ball $B_{X^*}$ of the dual $X^*$ such that, for every $g\in B_{X^*}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is $f\in M$ with $$\sup\{|g(x)-f(x)|: x\in A\}\le\varepsilon.$$

The sufficiency of the latter condition is true and I am very confident that the condition without the requirement $M\subseteq B_{X^*}$ is necessary.
The obvious question: Is the stated characterization true?

I want the ask-johnson-tag back! @BillJohnson

Here $F=X$ right?
PS: me too!

Condition (2) says that $B_{X^}$ (or equivalently $X^$) is separable w.t.to the seminorm $|\cdot|_{\infty,A}$, and this condition is the same for $A$ or $\overline A$. But I don't see the equivalence of  (1) for $A$ and for $\overline A$. Is it obvious that if a bounded absolutely convex set is weakly metrizable, so is its closure?

For bounded absolutely convex and weakly metrizable sets $A$ also the closure is weakly metrizable. The reason is that, by absolute convexity, the uniformity induced on $A$ is metrizable and then you can consider the completion as a uniform space which is still metrizable and contains the closure of $A$. This argument is from Theorem 1.4 of Kalton's Some forms of the closed graph theorem https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/some-forms-of-the-closed-graph-theorem/20C8CA3463AEB1803209BB77EE5C146D

Consider the following statement (S), for a bounded operator $T:Y\to X$ between normed spaces $X,Y$:
(S) The set $T(B_Y)$ is $\sigma(X,X^)$-metrisable iff $T^(X^)$ is $|\cdot|_{Y^}$-separable.
If $Y=X$ and $T=1_X$, this is the well-known weak metrisability theorem of the unit ball. If $T$ is the inclusion map of $Y:=\mathbb R\cdot A\subset X$, for a bounded absolutely convex subset $A\subset X$, normed by the Minkowski functional of $A$, (S) is the original statement.

It seems to me that (S) is always true ; I'm not sure about how to deduce directly from the standard case $T=1_X$, but following the proof of the latter it seems it generalises plainly. (One can also first reduce it to the case of Banach spaces, since clearly one can assume $X$ Banach, and per your comment $A$ closed, which implies the note $|\cdot|_Y$ is also Banach; but it seems this is not necessary because completeness is never used).

The dual statement (S'), that generalises analogously the theorem of weak* metrisability of the dual ball, I guess is also true (but didn't check all details): The set  $T^(B_{X^})$ is $\sigma(Y^,Y)$-metrisable iff $T(Y)$ is $|\cdot|_{X}$-separable*.

I end to believe that $(S)$ is true -- but I don't see how it proves the characterization.

We take $Y:=\mathbb R\cdot A$ with $B_Y:=A$, and $T:Y\to X$ the (continuous) inclusion map, so the "if" part of (S) is the "if" part of the original characterization . The dual norm $|\cdot|{Y*}$ is the uniform norm $|\cdot|{\infty,A}$, and $T^:X^\to Y^$ is the restriction map, so in this case the "only if" part of (S) means: "the set of restrictions of the $f\in X^$ to $Y$ is separable wrto $|\cdot|{\infty,A}$, which is the "only if" part of the characterization (separability of $T^(X^)$ or  $T^*(B{X^*}$ of course is the same). I miss something maybe?

(to be precise, the norm of $Y$ above is the Minkowski functional of $A$)

In the question, the crucial part (which I do not see) is whether one can choose the countable set $M$ in the unit ball of $X^*$. I suspect that (S) is rather related to the characterization of weak metrizability without this assumtion on $M$.

This I don't get... If $X^$ is separable wrto some (semi)norm, then every subset of it is also separable, no? That is, if $M\subset X^$ has $|\cdot|{\infty,A}$ closure containing  $B{X^}$, we can make another $M'\subset B_{X^}$ which dense as well (Thank you for your patience)

Ah, I think I've got it! Taking for granted that there is ${f_k:k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq X^$ such that, for all $g\in B_{X^}$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, there is $k\in \mathbb N$ with $|g-f_k|A \le 1/n$, one can define $f{k,n}$ as an arbitrary element $h\in B_{X^}$ with $|f_k-h|A\le 1/n$ if there is such an $h$ and $f{k,n}=0$, else. For $g\in B_{X^}$ and $k\in\mathbb N$ with $|g-f_k|A\le 1/n$ we then have $|g-f{k,n}|_A\le |g-f_k|A+|f_k-f{k,n}|A\le 2/n$. Hence ${f{k,n}: k,n\in\mathbb N}$ is a countable subset of $B_X^*$ which is $|\cdot|_A$ dense.

Thank you very much, Pietro. I suggest that you write an answer so that you get the bounty.

Just saw this as I don't frequently check FA tagged posts. A for your first comment, maybe we should have an ask-majer tag.

You are welcome Jochen, I'm always learning something from you! Thank you Bill, this is very kind and also very funny!

To summarise, the above characterisation may be seen as a case of:
for a bounded operator $T:Y\to X$ between normed spaces $X,Y$:
Thm. Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces, and $T:Y\to X$ a linear bounded operator. Then the set $T(B_Y)$ is $\sigma(X,X^*)$-metrisable iff $T^*(X^*)$ is $\|\cdot\|_{Y^*}$ -separable.
The proof follows the lines of the well-known theorem of weak metrisability of the unit ball, which is the particular case with $X=Y$ and $T=\text{id}_X$.
Rmk. The latter condition can be stated equivalently as: $T^*(B_{X^*})$ is $\|\cdot\|_{Y^*}$ -separable: for, in general, if an absorbing subset $S$ of a normed space $V$ is separable, the space $V=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} nS$ is separable, and conversely, if  $V$ as a metric space is separable, every subset of it is separable in the induced metric.
To read the original characterisation as a case of the above theorem, we take $Y:=\mathbb R\cdot A$ normed by the Minkowski functional of the bounded absolutely convex subset $A\subset X$, and $T$  the (linear, continuous) inclusion map of $Y$ into $X$. So $T^*:X^*\to Y^*$ is the restriction map and the dual norm $\|\cdot\|_{Y^*}$ coincides with the uniform norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty,A}$ (which is a seminorm on the whole $X^*$). Then $A$ is $\sigma(X,X^*)$-metrisable  iff $TB_{Y}$ is $\sigma(X,X^*)$-metrisable, and $X^*$ is separable w.r.to the (semi)norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty,A}$ iff $T^*X^*$, or $T^*(B_{X^*})$, is $\|\cdot\|_{Y^*}$-separable.
[after thinking a little more] Actually the statement (Thm) I wrote is not much more general than the characterisation quoted in the original post, which seems to me, instead, a non-obvious generalisation (which I'm glad I learned, thank you Jochen!) of the $w$-measurability theorem of the ball, i.e. the case of $T=1_X$ and $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)=(X,\|\cdot\|_Y)$;  non obvious even for two norms on the same space (this is in fact the relevant generalisation).
Specifically: let $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be normed spaces on the same vector space, the norm $\|\cdot\|_Y$ being stronger than $\|\cdot\|_X$, so that $X^*$ is a subset of $Y^*$. Then the original characterisation reads:

The ball of $Y$ is metrisable in the weak topology of $X$ iff the
ball of $X^*$ is separable in the strong topology  of $Y^*$.

